# Get "visible" viewport zone after scaling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scale, viewport

I use viewport in my web app, which enables scaling:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 ,maximum-scale=2.0" />
```

After zoom-in and zoom-out, I need to know what pixels are shown on the screen.

for example, when I use initial display I see 0 (div left) - 1024 (div right) pixels of my div (width), but after zoom-in, the area is different, because the div is "wider" and I see only a part of it.

Is there any way to calculate this data?
I tried using the scrollerLeft parameter (after zoom it is not "0"), but it returns 0 (seems like not updating).

Answer (score 0):

you will get the width of the div

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/p9g5eegu/3/)

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    findwidth()
})

findwidth()

function findwidth() {
    var a = $('.left').width()
    var b = $('.right').width()
    var c = $(window).width()

    $('.width1').html(a)
    $('.width2').html(b)
    $('.full').html(c)
}
```